# Custom animation doesn't work with inline elements only in Chrome/Opera

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm playing with an animation I [found](https://gist.github.com/CodeMyUI/530e25ec020cfbfc68526a2a56cb0247) on CodeMyUi.

Here is my code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZxbVgv?editors=1100

Html:

```
<h1 class="linear-wipe"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Veniam at officiis deserunt aliquid, possimus voluptas mollitia perspiciatis. Minus sed nulla in recusandae quaerat ut, quos obcaecati nihil eligendi, aspernatur quidem?</h1>

<span class="linear-wipe"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Veniam at officiis deserunt aliquid, possimus voluptas mollitia perspiciatis. Minus sed nulla in recusandae quaerat ut, quos obcaecati nihil eligendi, aspernatur quidem?</span>
```

Less:

```
span{
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.linear-wipe {  
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #00F 20%, #FF0 40%, #FF0 60%, #00F 80%);
  background-size: 200% auto;

  color: #000;
  background-clip: text;
  text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;

  animation: shine 1s linear infinite;
  @keyframes shine {
    to {
      background-position: 200% center;
    }
  }
}
```

The problem occurs in the span element when the texts is on multiple lines and viewed in webkit browsers. Example:

[image]

Displaying the element as inline-bock or block will solve the problem but my question is if somebody can explain why this happens.

Answer (score 1):

> span is the standard inline element. Historically, span elements can't
>   be animated with CSS. In order to animate them, you'll need to give
>   them a display property.

Read more [**Here**](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/issues/515) and [**Here**](http://blog.cee.moe/why-css-transform-doesnt-work-on-inline-elements.html)
.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm new to animations and actually it didn't cross my mind inlines can't be animated. But this case is quite interesting because this example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KozbZP shows animations can be applied and work well with spans but my original question does not work with Webkit browsers only and one of the reasons is the `background-clip: text` property